# How to merge between two local repositories

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two local git repositories (one is a clone of master repo,  other is a clone of fork of master). Is there a way to merge a branch of one with the same branch from other?

Note - I can't just add the master as upstream , because we have some issues that way currently - [git fetch fails due to pack-object failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359777/git-fetch-fails-due-to-pack-object-failure) .

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could add another remote repository such as 'local'.

Try the following way (which I just ran successfully):

(Suppose your local repositories are MyGitRepo.git and AnotherRepo.git in the same folder)

in MyGitRepo.git folder:

```
$: git remote add local ../AnotherRepo
$: git fetch local
$: git merge local/master
```

If master is the branch you want to merge.

After `git fetch local`, you will probably see the following:

```
$ git fetch local
From ../AnotherRepo
 * [new branch]      master     -> local/master
```

which means that another tracking branch is successfully made to track the (other) local repository.

Ref:
 read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277792/how-can-i-use-git-with-multiple-remote-repositories) about multiple remote repositories

Comment: this was easy :) , should have given it a try

Comment: Note that using relative paths (like the example here shows) is pretty broken under git-for-windows. I had to use absolute paths.

Comment: Thanks: if you also face `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories` -> add `--allow-unrelated-histories` for more information check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase

Comment: This procedure adds ../AnotherRepo as a permanent repository of MyGitRepo.git so maybe, after merging both repositiores we might want to delete the ../AnotherRepo reference from MyGitRepo.git.