# How to compare same file from 2 different repositories in Intellij?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

Suppose I made changes to a file `a.java` in repository `repo1` and committed my changes to a local branch `branch1`. Next I came to know that I can not directly push my change to `repo1`. Rather I have to fork the repo and then create a branch and PR from there. So now I forked `repo1` to `repo2` and created a branch. `origin/branch2` and checked it out. Now how can I compare the file `a.java` from `repo1` branch `branch1` and bring the changes to `repo2` branch `branch2`? It would be nice if I can do it in Intellij.

Comment: I think you can just merge the two branches as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360077/how-to-merge-between-two-local-repositories).

Comment: Looks to me like you can just copy and paste the file content and no further steps should be necessary.

Comment: There is a blog post on how to keep the fork up-to-date, please see:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/01/git-questions-how-to-keep-a-git-fork-up-to-date/

Also you can compare files with a diff viewer, please see:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/comparing-files-and-folders.html

Answer (score 0):

If the file is visible from your local repository (as in the other two repos are set as remotes) then git doesn't care.... you can provide the path to the two files and it will diff them (it really doesn't require any relation between the files... it can be 2 completely different projects altogether):

```
git diff repo1/branch1:path-to-file repo2/branch2:path-to-file2
```

That should work.

Now.. getting one IDE to do that kind of stuff? I don't think you will be able to pull it off. Might need to consider checking out the file from one branch to your local branch so that then you can pick the parts you want to keep and the ones you want to discard:

```
git checkout repo1/branch1 -- path-to-file
```

Or

```
git show repo1/branch1:path-to-file > path-locally # if the files do not have the same path in the 2 branches
```

Then feel free to check the things you want to keep on the IDE.

## important

I am assuming your working tree is clean and you have no pending changes on the files you want to play with.